# Is there a way to reduce how many service injections I have on Startup class in ASP.NET core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

I am developing an API using .net core and I am about to use dependency injection but I realized that having the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method in the Startup class clogged with service injections is what I do not like. For example...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")));
        services.AddScoped<IServiceOne, ServiceOne>();
        services.AddScoped<IServiceTwo, ServiceTwo>();
        services.AddScoped<IServiceThree, ServiceThree>();
        services.AddScoped<IServiceFour, ServiceFour>();
        //more and more services. This could go on and on and that would make the whole class ugly
    }
```

Is there a way I can put all these services in one class and call them in the Startup class?
I'm using asp.net3.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Extract the code you want into a separate method. Or create an extension method accepting an `IServicesCollection` that registers the services you want. That's what `AddDbContext` does

Comment: I don't quite understand. Could you kindly direct me to a link or article where I can see  this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AddDbContext` is an extension method that configures and registers a `DbContext`-derived class with `IServicesCollection`. You can use the same pattern and create your own extension methods that add specific services, eg :

```
static class MyExtensions
{
    static IServiceCollection AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IServiceOne, ServiceOne>();
        services.AddScoped<IServiceTwo, ServiceTwo>();
        services.AddScoped<IServiceThree, ServiceThree>();
        services.AddScoped<IServiceFour, ServiceFour>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

You could split the registrations into related services eg `AddAccounting`, `AddInventory` based on your application's modules or scenarios, putting all the registrations needed for a specific module in one place, eg :

```
static IServiceCollection AddAccounting(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connection=Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<Account>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    services.AddDbContext<Transaction>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    services.AddScoped<IServiceOne, ServiceOne>();
    services.AddScoped<IServiceTwo, ServiceTwo>();

    return services;
}

static IServiceCollection AddInventory(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connection=Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<Warehouse>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    services.AddDbContext<Product>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    services.AddScoped<IServiceThree, ServiceThree>();

    return services;
}
```

Comment: I've 1 question. If there are multiple classes injected via DI, can it slow down the app startup? I'm asking this question because it is being used in AWS Lambda function which I believe get's instantiated on each call/invoke. Thanks.

Comment: The same happens in ASP.NET Core MVC and Razor Pages - a new controller instance or PageModel is created for every request. The impact in AWS Lambda is *less* because Lambda can start more services if it has to